# What is the ubuntu 16.04 lts server default username & password?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, xubuntu, lubuntu

When i installed dual boot ubuntu 16.04 lts server i did not entry any ubuntu server login & password when i opened ubuntu server it wants  login & password.What     is the ubuntu 16.04 lts server default login & password ?or How to open this server?

Comment: i installed dual boot .& Server image boot

Answer (score 3):

Unless you use a special ISO, Ubuntu asks you to enter a username and password, in addition to the root password. Verify the installation and download the official ISO.

On this screen you select the time zone.
[image: timezone]

And this, which is the next screen, you enter the password for a user.
The password will be the same for the root user.
[image: User creation]

Images taken from: https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-18-04-lts-desktop-installation-guide-screenshots/

Comment: i did not see this .What can i do now?

Comment: Reinstall from the official media, and pay attention.